# Files not found in R when writing a package: what is the right approach?

Tags: r, r-package, plumber

I'm writing an R package using `plumber`. The main code:

```
#' @title startServer
#' @description Start the api server on port `port`
#'
#' @param port Port number
#' @return none
#' @examples
#' startServer(8000)
#' @export
startServer <- function(port) {
  port <- if (port == "")
    port = "8000"

  router_some <- plumber$new("R/some.R")
  router <- plumber$new()
  router$mount("/some", router_some)

  router$run(host = '0.0.0.0',
             port = strtoi(port),
             swagger = TRUE)
}
```

This code works fine if I run it from the R console:

```
startServer("8000")
Running plumber API at http://0.0.0.0:8000
Loading required namespace: swagger
Running Swagger UI  at http://127.0.0.1:8000/__swagger__/
```

However, whenver I run `check()`:

```
checking examples ... ERROR
  Running examples in ‘...’ failed
  The error most likely occurred in:

  > base::assign(".ptime", proc.time(), pos = "CheckExEnv")
  > ### Name: startServer
  > ### Title: startServer
  > ### Aliases: startServer
  > 
  > ### ** Examples
  > 
  > startServer(8000)
  Error in .subset2(public_bind_env, "initialize")(...) : 
    File does not exist: R/some.R
  Calls: startServer -> <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous>
  Execution halted
```

the file with the routes is not found anymore. How to point to the right file(s)?

---

I know I could use `plumber` programmatically, but than, I seem to loose a proper swagger file generation (no parameters).

Answer (score 0):

I you know how package building works, it's pretty straight forward: during build time, all the code is actually executed and stored as R objects/structures. What we need here is binding the router at build time, and exposing the function `startServer` when finished. Or: all router logic may be executed at build time. Only starting the server (`router$run`) should be in `startServer`

```
router_some <- plumber$new("R/some.R")
router <- plumber$new()
router$mount("/some", router_some)

#' @title startServer
#' @description Start the api server on port `port`
#'
#' @param port Port number
#' @return none
#' @examples
#' startServer(8000)
#' @export
startServer <- function(port) {
  port <- if (port == "")
    port = "8000"
  router$run(host = '0.0.0.0',
             port = strtoi(port),
             swagger = TRUE)
}
```